# HTML Footer - Can`t put it after a body with image

Tags: html, css, footer

I`m doing a (very) simple website for college but I got stuck. The idea is just have an image as body and an Iframe on header (we are not using html 5). It will have first, info and contact page that are gonna use the same header and footer

Until now I did it fine, things are working well with the header but I'm not getting to add the footer after the image, the content is always doing in the middle of the photo, I`m trying it in many different ways.

PS: Each page has a different photo with the same size in the body background.
The footer must be placed immediately after the image, with the same width (912px).

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style>

body{
margin:0px;
background:black;
background-image:url("photo02.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="top_nav">
<iframe src="navigation.html" width="100%" height="70" border="0" frameborder="no"></iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry, I`m still learning how to use it, I`m gonna check how to put the code here in a "readable" way.

Comment: Welcome @Jorge please have a look at this page for code formatting help: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks